# Is there anyway to download emulator image to configure it manually for Android Studio?

Tags: android

I want to animage for Android Studio Emulator **but I don't want to do that from AVD Manager.** I want to download it from a website so I can use this image in any other computer by copying and pasting it instead of wasting time every time I format my computer and reinstall Android Studio. 
Is there anyway to do that? Or it must be downloaded and configured by Android Studio? 

by the way, I use version 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator images are in `~/.android/avd` You can copy subdirectories (along with the .ini files) from there.